# adding an icon url to discord in visual studio

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add an icon `(iconurl="")` to the Text `+= $"Disclaimer:text.\\n";` so my uploaded icon will appear just in front of the Disclaimer text. Adding the iconurl = ""; gives me an CS0103 error:

> Iconurl does not exist in the current context

```
private EmbedFooterBuilder SetFooter()
{
     string StartTime = $"{setting.StartTime - DateTime.Now:d\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss}";
     string RaidCount = $"{setting.RaidCount}";
     string WinCount = $"{setting.WinCount}";
     string LossCount = $"{setting.LossCount}";

     string Text = "";
     Text += $"Host: {HostSAV.OT} | Uptime: {StartTime}\n";
     Text += $"Raids: {RaidCount} | Wins: {WinCount} | Losses: {LossCount}\n";
     Text += $"Disclaimer: text.\n";
    
     return  new EmbedFooterBuilder { Text = Text };
}
```